# How to interpret two-way ANOVA table (lmer) output in R?

Tags: r, lme4, anova

I have a 2 x 2 factorial design ("density", "fertilizer"), with block as random effect. I am trying to predict plant growth. How do I interpret this table? I have already checked to see that there is no interaction and it follows assumptions of ANOVA

```
   Sample data: 
        density <- c("low","low","low","low","high",high",high","high")
        fertilizer <- c("N","N","P","P","N","N","P","P")
        growth <- c(1,1,2,2,5,6,2,1)

    model <- lmer(growth~density + fertilizer + (1|block))


        Output:

        Fixed effects:
                 Estimate Std. Error       df t value Pr(>|t|)    
    (Intercept)   0.63351    0.06275 62.79670  10.096 8.92e-15 ***
    densityHigh   0.12473    0.07502 85.99111   1.663    0.100    
    fertlizerP    0.01209    0.00602 76.42369   0.422    0.005 **
```

Specifically, I'm trying to understand how to compare the first and last row?
My guess

1. (Intercept) is  Density: Low, Fertilizer: N
2. Density: Low is not different from Density: High (p > 0.05)

Not clear how to interpret (3)

3. Fertilizer: N is different from Fertilizer: P or

or is it: Density: Low, Fertilizer: N is different from Density: Low, Fertilizer: P

or is it: Density: Low, Fertilizer: N is different from Density: High, Fertilizer: P

Comment: What is block in your data.frame ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

N is different from P, regardless of the level of Density, or more precises for a 2x2 design: N is different from P for the mean value of Density. Or: if density is held constant and fertilizer is changed from N to P, there is an growth increase of .012

[Visualisation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZBoQ.jpg) and [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OE46w0RqmQA)

Comment: though this should realy be on crossvalidated